# AutoHotkey's MouseClickDrag issues in dealing with selecting Paint.NET images squared area?

Tags: autohotkey, paint.net

(If you want to reproduce this example, please download Paint.NET from [**here**](http://www.getpaint.net/), it's free and it's got more functions than Microsoft Paint).

When you open Paint.NET, load a simple image and take rectangular selection as instrument.

I've written this simple script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

^d::
MouseClickDrag, Left, 365, 434, 906, 460
;You can change mouse coordinates as you wish
Send, ^c
Return
```

Run it with `Ctrl` + `d`.

I'm not able to select the area described by those coordinates, while using the rectangular color filling instrument works fine.

It seems AutoHotkey does not highlight the area if I use the rectangular selector.

Have you got the same issue?

Comment: Remove the `SendMode Input` or change it to `SendMode Event`. P.S. If you want to crop images with AHK, I suggest looking into [GDI+](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/29449-gdi-standard-library-145-by-tic/).

Comment: @MCL, great. You should have made this an answer, not a simple comment :)

Comment: I'm glad. There you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SendMode Input` doesn't work, [Event](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm) usually does. Unfortunately, it's not as fast as `Input`, so playing around with `SetKeyDelay` may help going against that effect.
However, if you're looking for a way to manipulate images automatically, I recommend using [GDI+](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/29449-gdi-standard-library-145-by-tic/).